# Export Product Sku, Product Name, and Product Price in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, export

I'm trying to get a list of all of our products in CSV or Excel format which has the SKU, Product Name, & Product Price. Is there is a way to acquire this from Magento2?

Comment: you can follow the below link: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-export.html and let me know if you need to another way

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume that you have created `simple module`. Now, create controller for create csv file and download at `app/code/MS/Helloworld/Controller/Index/ExportCsv.php` and paste the below code :

```
<?php
namespace MS\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class ExportCsv extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\File\Csv
     */
    protected $csvProcessor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context            $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory            $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory     $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\File\Csv                      $csvProcessor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList  $directoryList
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
    ) {
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
        $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * CSV Create and Download
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** Add yout header name here */
        $content[] = [
            'entity_id' => __('Entity ID'),
            'sku' => __('Sku'),
            'name' => __('Product Name'),
            'price' => __('Product Price'),
        ];

        $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection();
        
        $fileName = 'product_data_file.csv'; // Add Your CSV File name

        $filePath =  $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . "/" . $fileName;

        while ($product = $collection->fetchItem()) {
            $content[] = [
                $product->getEntityId(),
                $product->getSku(),
                $product->getName(),
                $product->getPrice()
            ];
        }
        $this->csvProcessor->setEnclosure('"')->setDelimiter(',')->saveData($filePath, $content);
        return $this->fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            [
                'type'  => "filename",
                'value' => $fileName,
                'rm'    => true, // True => File will be remove from directory after download.
            ],
            DirectoryList::MEDIA,
            'text/csv',
            null
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store Manager for Magento app allows exporting separate fields of the product in any format